# How to change image button on list view when on long click

Tags: android, android-listview, listitem

For example when i press longclick on one item on listview , its actual button will turn to delete button. I try like `next_sign.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.delete);` but, it force close.

```
lv.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                //next_sign.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.delete);
                return true;
            }
        });
```

```
12-28 13:44:34.251: E/AndroidRuntime(9108): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-28 13:44:34.251: E/AndroidRuntime(9108): java.lang.NullPointerException
12-28 13:44:34.251: E/AndroidRuntime(9108):     at com.mycos.cycleborg.PreviousActivity$3.onItemLongClick(MenuListActivity.java:129)
```

Comment: Is your `ImageButton` is present in every list item..?

Comment: yes, present in every list item, by the way i got the answer here.. tysm for you help:)
I already got the answer, thanks you so much ...

    View subview = view.findViewById(R.id.next_sign);
    subview.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.delete);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to declare two buttons of your first item and delete button at same position in your layout 
make visibility of your original button to

```
android:visibility="visible"
```

and make visibility of delete button to gone in layout using

```
android:visibility="gone"
```

in programming

```
lv.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
              Original_Button.setVisibility(View.Gone);
               delete_Button.setVisibility(View.Visible); 
                return true;
            }
        });
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int arg2, long arg3) {
   Button mButton = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.button);
   mButton.setVisibility(View.Visible); 
   return true;
}
```